# Embedded images order

Tags: sql, postgresql

Lets consider simple table for products of some e-commerce site

```
product (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, title TEXT, description TEXT, price REAL)
```

and separate table for embedded images

```
product_images (id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY, product_id INTEGER, image_url VARCHAR(256))
```

I want to set specific order of showing these images on site. The first thing I came up with is: add numeric column "position" to "product_images" which represents position in that order (for example position=2 means image is showing second). But in this case data integrity can be lost when some images are deleted. Are there other options?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a *position* column to the *product_images* table as you mentioned.

Then you have multiple solutions:

1. You always select with `an order by` clause on this column, so even if there is a gap between positions, images are well sorted at the front-end. In your backoffice, let the user set any integer he wants.
2. You want always have continuous position number, so you have to create a `trigger` wich will lower all position by 1 for all the superiors position of the deleted image. This case will oblige you to think about update, deletion and new image on an existing postion.

Answer (score 0):

You can form hierarchy of images instead of position , like adding additional column of parent_image_id (for first position it would be null) ,for every product there will be different image heirarchy.
while presenting, call as per parent child hierarchy which will solve your data integrity issue. [ref this](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/3FE1A8FB.1030101%40lorenso.com)